# Applications launched in wine crash with GLXBadFBConfig

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, opengl

I try to use PlayOnLinux to run SAP Gui for Windows, MS Office and other programs on Ubuntu 20.04 on an older laptop (the relevant info is that it has Intel HDA3000 GPU)
I have been using Office 2016 on this particular installation, and though it did crash sometimes, it was usable. фс

But now almost every program crash on start with GLXBadFBConfig error. Probably it broke after some update, but I didn't notice it at that time. I found a few posts about newer MESA drivers requiring MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE setting, but it does not work in my case.
I have tried many WINE versions, and, desperate, founad that 2.22 does indeed launch my programs, but works terribly slow. My guess is that it is too old to use MESA properly and renders on CPU.

Is there a reason why wine might ignore MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE setting?
Is there a way to confirm it's used?

Answer (score -1):

Try , to install wine again or update it : it should work also try these

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=34889

---

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/mfw36e/x_error_of_failed_request_glxbadfbconfig_after/

Comment: Answers that contain links are also expected to describe what these links do.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.